# zod: set min max after transform string to number

Tags: typescript, zod

I have number or numeric string, I want transform it to number and continue validate it by `.min()` `.max()`, but it don't work as I expected

```js
const numberValid = z.number().or(z.string().regex(/^\d+$/).transform(Number));

const positiveNumber = numberValid.min(0); // method don't exist
```

Comment: I receive response on github repo - https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/931

Answer (score 20):

As of version `3.20`, you can use [`z.coerce.number()`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#coercion-for-primitives) like so:

```
const numberValid = z.coerce.number().min(0)

numberValid.parse(123) // OK
numberValid.parse(-123) // ERROR
numberValid.parse("123") // OK
numberValid.parse("-123") // ERROR
```

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that the `transform` is going to return a `z.ZodEffect` which has methods for doing further transformations, but has lost track of the fact that it was originally `z.string`. The `min` method from `z.number` isn't accessible because the outer type is going to be `z.ZodUnion` which also doesn't know about the `min` refinement.

I think to get the behavior you're looking for something like this might be the approach I would take:

```js
const thing = z
  .number()
  .or(z.string().regex(/\d+/).transform(Number))
  .refine((n) => n >= 0);
```

Which is admittedly a little lack luster because we can't rely on `min` with its simplified syntax and nicer errors. You could solve the latter problem by adding a `{ message: 'value was less than 0' }` as the second argument to `refine`.

### Edit

This has gotten a bit of attention and I realized there is another way of doing this. You can use [`preprocess`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#preprocess) to handle strings before handing the value off to `z.number`. If you do it this way you can still leverage `.min` with all of the nice error messages and things.

```
const numberValid2 = z.preprocess(
  (input) => {
    const processed = z.string().regex(/^\d+$/).transform(Number).safeParse(input);
    return processed.success ? processed.data : input;
  },
  z.number().min(0),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 z.string() 
.transform((year) => parseInt(year)) 
.pipe(z.number().min(1900)) 
.transform((year) => year.toString())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with supporting information as to how this solves the problem